# ‘error: ‘EXAMPLE_FUNCTION’ was not declared in this scope ’ happend when I complie mysqlc++ connector1.1.3 examples

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I am trying to install mysqlc++ connector1.1.3 to my ubuntu os by compiling source code,but it reported "error: ‘EXAMPLE_FUNCTION’ was not declared in this scope " when I compling the example. Is there somebody facing the same error? Forgiving my poor in English.

Comment: `EXAMPLE_FUNCTION` is not, in itself, an error. Post/read/understand the ***entire*** error message.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met the same error,just add "#include "examples.h"" in the top of standalone_example.cpp.Maybe the author of mysqlc++ connector ignored that.